# Overlay normal desnity curves in R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to overlay normal density curves over my stacked histograms in R using **ggplot**. bsa are numerical measures and they are recorded for two groups, treatment and control.

I have created stacked histograms for the two groups. I get an error with stat_function about the mapping needing to be a list of unevaluated mappings.

Any advice on how to do this would be appreciated.

```
ggplot(data=bsa, aes(x=bsa)) +geom_histogram(colours(distinct=TRUE)) + facet_grid(group~.) +
  stat_function(dnorm(x, mean(bsa$bsa),sd(bsa$bsa)))+
  ggtitle("Histogram of BSA amounts by group")
```

Comment: Welcome @A M. To increase the likelihood of getting an answer, you should post a reproducible piece of code and the exact error message.

Answer (score 3):

Using `stat_function(...)` with facets is tricky. `stat_function(...)` takes an argument `args=...` which needs to be a named list of the extra arguments to the function (so in your case, `mean` and `sd`). The problem is that these cannot appear in `aes(...)` so you have to add the curves manually. Here is an example.

```
set.seed(1)   # for reproducible example
df <- data.frame(bsa=rnorm(200, mean=rep(c(1,4),each=100)), 
                 group=rep(c("test","control"),each=100))
# calculate mean and sd by group
stats <- aggregate(bsa~group, df, function(x) c(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x)))
stats <- data.frame(group=stats[,1],stats[,2])

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=bsa)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..,fill=group), color="grey30")+
  with(stats[stats$group=="control",],stat_function(data=df[df$group=="control",],fun=dnorm, args=list(mean=mean, sd=sd)))+
  with(stats[stats$group=="test",],stat_function(data=df[df$group=="test",],fun=dnorm, args=list(mean=mean, sd=sd)))+
  facet_grid(group~.)
```

[image]

This is rather ugly, so I usually just calculae the curves external to `ggplot` and add them using `geom_line(...)`.

```
x <- with(df, seq(min(bsa), max(bsa), len=100))
dfn <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(stats), 
                            function(i) with(stats[i,],data.frame(group, x, y=dnorm(x,mean=mean,sd=sd)))))
ggplot(df, aes(x=bsa)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..,fill=group), color="grey30")+
  geom_line(data=dfn, aes(x, y))+
  facet_grid(group~.)
```

[image]

This makes the `ggplot` code much more readable and produces pretty much the same thing.

Notice that if you wanted to overlay a kernel density estimate, rather than a normal curve, this would be a lot easier:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=bsa)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..,fill=group), color="grey30")+
  stat_density(geom="line")+
  facet_grid(group~.)
```

[image]