# Evaluate dnorm for multiple parameter values and the same argument

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am trying to accomplish the same as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32599888/overlay-normal-desnity-curves-in-r-using-ggplot), namely overlaying multiple histrograms with densities. 
The solution in the referred post works, but it made me wonder if calculation of the `dfn` can be done with newer packages like `purrr`/`purrrlyr`:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(bsa=rnorm(200, mean=rep(c(1,4),each=100)), 
                 group=rep(c("test","control"),each=100))

stats <- df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(m = mean(bsa), sd = sd(bsa))
x <- with(df, seq(min(bsa), max(bsa), len=100))

dfn <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(stats), 
                            function(i) with(stats[i,],data.frame(group, x, y=dnorm(x,mean=m,sd=sd)))))
```

To perform the inner `lapply` part, I have been trying stuff along the lines of

```
stats %>%
    dplyr::group_by(group) %>%
    purrr::map(x, dnorm, m, sd)
```

That is, passing on `m` and `sd` from stats and using the same `x`. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.
(Once the inner part is accomplished, I can pass on the result to `do.call`, so that is not a problem).

Comment: Is there a typo? Should `mean=mean` be `mean=m`?

Comment: You're right -- that's a type! I'll edit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go `dplyr`, I think you don't really need to compute `stats` nor `x` separately. I'd do:

```
dfn_2 <-
  df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(bsa), funs(min, max)) %>% 
  arrange(group) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  transmute(
    x = seq(first(min), first(max), length.out = n()), 
    y = dnorm(x, mean(bsa), sd(bsa))
  ) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

all.equal(dfn, dfn_2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Alternatively, here are two approaches that I do **not** recommend. Just to demonstrate it is possible, and how you could have done what you were trying:

```
dfn_3 <-
  stats %>% 
  split(.$group) %>% 
  map2_df(names(.), ~ tibble(group = .y, x, y = dnorm(x, .x$m, .x$sd)))

# # A tibble: 200 x 3
#      group         x            y
#      <chr>     <dbl>        <dbl>
#  1 control -1.888921 6.490182e-09
#  2 control -1.809524 1.045097e-08
#  3 control -1.730128 1.672139e-08
#  4 control -1.650731 2.658301e-08
#  5 control -1.571334 4.199062e-08
#  6 control -1.491938 6.590471e-08
#  7 control -1.412541 1.027772e-07
#  8 control -1.333145 1.592550e-07
#  9 control -1.253748 2.451917e-07
# 10 control -1.174352 3.750891e-07
# # ... with 190 more rows

all.equal(dfn, as.data.frame(mutate_at(dfn_3, vars(group), as.factor)))
# [1] TRUE


dfn_4 <-
  stats %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  transmute(x = list(x), y = map(x, dnorm, m, sd)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  tidyr::unnest()

# # A tibble: 200 x 3
#      group         x            y
#     <fctr>     <dbl>        <dbl>
#  1 control -1.888921 6.490182e-09
#  2 control -1.809524 1.045097e-08
#  3 control -1.730128 1.672139e-08
#  4 control -1.650731 2.658301e-08
#  5 control -1.571334 4.199062e-08
#  6 control -1.491938 6.590471e-08
#  7 control -1.412541 1.027772e-07
#  8 control -1.333145 1.592550e-07
#  9 control -1.253748 2.451917e-07
# 10 control -1.174352 3.750891e-07
# # ... with 190 more rows

all.equal(dfn, as.data.frame(dfn_4))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Why don't you recommend your last two options?

Comment: Because I find the code less clear. There's `x` that's found in the global environment, then `m` and `sd` in the scope of the `stats` data frame... The emphasis on "*not*" is maybe a bit too much though ;-) . (And the first approach is not completely satisfying anyway: what I don't like about it is that in `transmute` there's almost no relation between the rows of the resulting data frame and of the original data frame. It's a bit artificial anyway that they've got the same number of rows)

Comment: My approach would have been to `summarise` to one row of params for each `group`, then `do(data_frame(...))` to generate the `x` of arbitrary number of rows, rather than `transmute` in place. That's probably most similar to your last example, but without creating external variables.

Comment: I'd be interested to see it, why not post it as an answer, for completeness? :)

Answer (score 1):

Per @[Aurele](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6197649/aur%C3%A8le)'s request, here's my take:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(bsa=rnorm(200, mean=rep(c(1,4),each=100)), 
           group=rep(c("test","control"),each=100))
```

#### Option 1:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(mean, sd, min, max)) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%                                                        
  mutate(newdata = list(data_frame(x = seq(min, max, length.out = 80)))) %>%     
  unnest() %>%                                                             
  mutate(dens = dnorm(x, mean, sd)) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(data = df, aes(bsa, y = ..density.., fill = group), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(x, dens, color = group), size = 2)
```

#### Option 2:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(mean, sd, min, max)) %>% 
  group_by(group, mean, sd, min, max) %>% 
  do(data_frame(x = seq(.$min, .$max, length.out = 80))) %>% 
  mutate(dens = dnorm(x, mean, sd)) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(data = df, aes(bsa, y = ..density.., fill = group), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(x, dens, color = group), size = 2)
```

My two methods are the same, just slightly different in generating the new data.

1. Group by **group**
2. Generate summary statistics
3. Group by **group** again
4. Create a new `list` column named `newdata` with a sequence of **x** values from **min** to **max** of **bsa**, then `tidyr::unnest` to expand it

#### OR

3. Group by all the stats to keep them in the environment
4. Generate a whole new dataframe with `do` for the new **x** values, each of which inherits the stats columns from the environment

#### THEN

5. Generate the densities at each **x** with the appropriate **mean** and **sd**.
6. Make a plot of the densities as lines
7. Add a layer with a histogram of the original data (with `y = ..density..` for scaling)

The only difference between my approach and Aurele's is that they generate a new 
x value for each row of your original data. If you have 50-100 data points, that's a good idea. If you have <20 data points, your density lines will be jumpy and not smooth. If you have >500 data points, you're wasting your time with overly high resolution that isn't needed and takes up memory. The default in `ggplot2` for curve generation is usually 80 points, so that's what I used (`length.out = 80` in both options).

[image]